# How many strings of digits of length $n$ contains a substring of $k$ identical consecutive digits?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f(n, k)$ be the number of strings of digits of length $n$ that contain a substring of $k$ identical consecutive digits. What would be a recursive or closed-form way to compute $f(n, k)$?

For example,  $f(n, 2)=10^n - 10\times 9^n$ by using complementary counting. There are $10$ choices for each digit ignoring the restriction, and there are $9$ choices for each digit after the first if we can't repeat any two consecutive digits.

Comment: The coupled recurrences in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946514/number-of-bit-strings-of-length-n-with-no-k-11-consecutive-0s-and-no-k-21/1946530#19465300) are an approach that will work for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

> We consider the alphabet $V=\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. We are looking for the number $g(n,k)$  of strings of length $n$ having runs at most length $k-1$. The wanted  number is  $$f(n,k)=10^n-g(n,k)$$

Strings with no consecutive equal characters at all are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a q-ary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{qz}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}

Replacing occurrences of $0$ in a Smirnov word by one up to $k-1$ zeros generates words having runs of $0$ with length less than $k$.
\begin{align*}\
z\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots+z^{k-1}=\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}
\end{align*}

The  same can be done for the other digits.

> The resulting generating function is for $q=10$
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1- \frac{10\cdot \frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}
> &=\frac{1-z^k}{1-qz+(q-1)z^{k}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series we obtain the number of wanted words of length $n$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(n,k)}&=10^n-g(n,k)\\
> &\color{blue}{=[z^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^k}{1-10z+9z^{k}}\right)}
> \end{align*}

**Example:** Let's look at an example. We take $k=3$. We obtain with some help of Wolfram Alpha
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-10z}-\frac{1-z^3}{1-10z+9z^{k}}=10 z^3 + \color{blue}{190} z^4 + 2800 z^5 +\cdots
\end{align*}

The blue colored coefficient of $z^4$ shows there are $\color{blue}{190}$ words of length $4$ built from characters $\{0,1,2,\ldots 9\}$ and runs of a digit with length at least $k=3$.

The number $190$ is easily to check. Strings of length $n=4$ and runs with length $3$ have the form
\begin{align*}
abbb\qquad\text{or}\qquad bbba
\end{align*}
with $a,b\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ given $2\cdot 10\cdot 10=200$ different strings. Since $abbb=bbba$ iff $a=b$ we have $10$ strings  counted     twice    and to subtract from $200$ giving a total of 
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(4,3)=190}
\end{align*}