# Number of ways to arrange $A,A,A,B,C,C$ such that no $2$ consecutive letters are the same

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

There is a question from my problem set that I am facing difficulty in solving.

It says to find the number of ways to arrange $A, A, A, B, C, C$ so that no $2$ consecutive letters are the same.

Some of the comments are suggesting this is a duplicate but in that question, the frequency of the letters was the same making it easier to solve by inclusion-exclusion principle. Not the case here, however.

**My approach:**

I tried to formulate cases where no $2$ consecutive letters would be the same. I tried using the gap method wherein I created a scenario like this,
$-  A-  A - A- $
Now we can see that there are $4$ spaces and three letters left to fill, and no restrictions, so we get $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 3! = 24$.
However, this is obviously not the only case where this is possible. I think this might be solvable with the inclusion-exclusion principle.

**Approach 2:**

If we take cases for the consecutive letters being the same, then we can perhaps subtract from the total number of cases, for example, we can take
$2 A$'s being consecutive and then $3A$'s and then $2B$'s and so on...
This is where I require help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrangements of a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c in which no three consecutive letters are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944807/arrangements-of-a-a-a-b-b-b-c-c-c-in-which-no-three-consecutive-letters-are-the)

Comment: @Jam: That one is significantly more complicated than this.

Comment: Your approach 1 goes wrong, **first** because you're treating the two Cs as distinguishable (this overcounts by a factor of two), **second** because the middle two positions in `-A-A-A-` _must_ be filled with something (this counts some invalid soluions such as `CAABAC`), **third** because you can fill one of those positions with _two_ letters if you have enough letters, which you will have if you leave both the ends blank (this misses some valid positions such as `ABCACA`).

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing, I had the same thought as I was checking my solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine the order of the B, C, C, ignoring the As. There are $3$ possibilities for that.

Now you have, for example, `-C-B-C-` and you need to fill three of the four open slots with As. There are $4$ ways to do that -- you just have to choose which slot you *don'* fill.

The cases where this *won't* produce a valid sequence is if the two Cs were adjacent in the initial sequence and *don't* get an A between them. That is, we need to subtract two for exactly the sequences `ABACCA` amd `ACCABA`, and our final count is
$$ 3\cdot 4 - 2 $$

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only case because according to what I have tried my count is higher than this and I don't feel like I have included all the cases too?

Comment: @PrakharNagpal: If I'm wrong, it shouldn't be hard to produce a concrete list of 11 different valid sequences. (Or just one sequence that isn't counted by my analysis).