# How many ways to order groups of people so that no 2 people from the same group are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have n people from Group 1, n' people from Group 2, and n'' people from Group 3. You want to place them in a line so that no 2 people from the same group are adjacent. Consider that people from the same group are not distinct. How many ways are there to do this? Can you generalize to k groups?

I was thinking of using stars and bars and I can see how you could do that with 2 groups, but I don't know how to add in the third group after. I also considered doing this with complimentary counting, but I don't know what would be an overcount/undercount. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How would you use Stars and Bars with two groups?

Comment: Well the bars would be the people from 1 group, and in the slots between I would force 1 person from the other group to go in each slot. Then there would be 2 places for the last star to go, in the front or in the back, so there would be 2 ways.

Comment: So...nothing to do with Stars and Bars, right?  You pick someone to start the list and the rest are then forced.

Comment: I suggest:  solve the problem for small $n$, look for patterns.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944807/arrangements-of-a-a-a-b-b-b-c-c-c-in-which-no-three-consecutive-letters-are-the) is a special case.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question when copying it down. There's a different number of people in each group so my answer would be wrong. Actually it would be n+n'-1 choose (n'-(n-1)) right?

Comment: Well, with different numbers there might be $0$ solutions.  If, say, $n_1=n_2=1$ and $n_3=100$, there are no solutions at all.

Comment: Well what if we assume $n + n' \geq n''$

Comment: What about the relationship between $n$ and $n'$ ?

Comment: Well we can say $a+b \geq c$ and a, b, c can be any of n, n', n''

Comment: You can as well use the symbols $a, b, c$ and say $a\leq b\leq c$, with $a+b>c$. Can you work this out ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I suggest studying the special case I linked to, $(n_1,n_2,n_3)=(3,3,3)$.  That's already a fair bit of work.

Comment: Instead of $n, n',n"$, I am suggesting simplified notatiom:  $a$ of one group, $b$ of another and $c$ of the third with simple constraints given so that you are absolutely certain that you can find a solution

Comment: I am reading that post now too and I think the answer about Laguerre series could be applicable to my question but I'm not advanced enough to understand it. I do understand how you can use PIE when you have numbers for each group though

Answer (score -2):

Given a total of ( n + n' + n'' ) people represented by the empty spaces:

{ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ }

For the first empty place, you have 3 choices (either from Group 1, Group 2, or Group 3). And for the next empty place, you only have 2 choices. For the subsequent empty places, you again have only 2 choices (different from the last one). This way, you have a total of 3 * 2^{n+n'+n''-1} ways to arrange this.

For any number of ( k ) groups, you can do the same:

k * (k-1)^{(total number of people) - 1}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is not correct, for example if you have exhausted the people from one of the groups then you do not have a choice of which group to pick from. Consider @lulu's example from the comments above.